# How to debug a NodeJS blocked event loop?

Tags: node.js, debugging, heroku, production-environment, event-loop

We have a NodeJS/Express server running in production, and occasionally, all requests are getting blocked.  The web requests are being received, but not processed (and they eventually all time out). After a few minutes, it'll begin accepting requests again, but then almost immediately begin blocking like before.

We've been trying to reproduce the issue locally but can't reproduce and determine what the cause is.  My guess is the event loop is getting blocked from either a synchronous operation that's taking too long to complete or doesn't complete at all.

Are there any ways to debug a live production system and figure out what's causing the block? I've searched, but could only find solutions for local development.  Is my best solution to look back at the logs, see where the last request that didn't block complete (before it started blocking), and debug that?

Using Node 6.2.2, Express 4.13.4, and running on Heroku.